# Was snowboarder Kelly Murphy chased by a bear?

Tags: japan, video

This YouTube video titled [*Snowboarder Girl Chased By Bear - I Was Singing Rihanna Work And Didn't Know It Was Behind Me!*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vT_PNKg3v7s) depicts a woman snowboarding in Japan. Occasionally, a running bear comes into shot in the background.

The description says:

> OMG! I was going through my snowboarding videos and I found a bear chasing me!!! I nearly got eaten!!!
>   This was at Hakuba 47 in Japan, filmed yesterday! Be careful people!!!

It was published on April 10 2016, by YouTuber [Kelly Murphy](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9vJHwocCZm6RFE9ZfGAJDg).

The bear subjectively looks fake to me. Is this genuine footage?

Comment: Does Japan even *have* wild bears?

Comment: [Apparently they do.](http://www.outdoorjapan.com/magazine/story_details/99)

Comment: Why does it look fake to you?

Comment: [According to the Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/weird-news/snowboarder-bear-chase-video-viral-fake-real-kelly-murphy-a6978721.html) Kelly Murphy said "Yes the video is real! I didn't know anything was happening at the time but it's so scary to watch it back now! I think I'll stick to the runs with my friends from now on lol." upon being contacted. That's the best I've got at the moment, but I'm pretty sure it's not gonna take more than a week for the internet to figure out if it's genuine or not.